# Use Excel in built FILTER function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am writing a vba macro to return array of values from a excel table based on certain conditions - 'all values in column A where Column B is some value'.

This is easy to get from an excel Filter function:
`=FILTER(Column A, Column B = some value)`

The table has more than 100k values and If I write a UDF or a For Loop in VBA to compare each index item - the response is very slow as compared to the inbuilt filter function.

I am trying something like
`Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter(Column A Range, Column B Range = "some value")`
But I am getting a error 13: type mismatch error.

```
    Sub testWorkSheetFunc()
     Dim filterCol, condCol As Range
     Set filterCol = 
           Sheets("InstrumentList").ListObjects("InstrumentList") 
           .ListColumns("strike").Range
    Set condCol = 
           Sheets("InstrumentList").ListObjects("InstrumentList") 
           .ListColumns("name").Range
    Dim arr As Variant    
    arr = Application.WorksheetFunction
          .Filter(filterCol, condCol = "some value")
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Filter` method is used to filter an array and return a new array based on a condition applied to that array. But here you're trying to filter two ranges `filterCol` and `condCol` together, which is causing the `type mismatch` error.

Comment: You cannot compare a multi-cell range to a value like this in VBA: `condCol = "some value"`